# UIActivityViewController : Set navigationbar color when User clicks on More Butoon

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using UIActivityViewController for sharing data from iOS application. When i test an app on Real device (iPhone6), UIActivityViewController works fine for all apps. But when I click on MORE button, navigation bar colour get changed.

I am using Xcode 7. [Screenshot URL](http://s13.postimg.org/c5m8yprt3/IMG_3548.jpg)

Code :

```
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:TRUE completion:nil];
```

Comment: you can upload screenshot in any other like dropbox,facebook and than send this link in comment so other can give its suggestion.

Comment: This is too little information. Can you please describe your problem in detail? Have you testes application on other devices or simulator?

Comment: I Don't want to change navigation bar colour. I have put the Screenshot URL in question. You can see the status bar and navigation bar colour has been changed.

Comment: @KTPATEL: tested app in simulator and iPad also. But result getting same in both devices.

Answer (score 0):

simply do this:

```
-(void) yourButtonActionMEthod{

      // for background color
  [nav.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

}
```

Comment: This code is not working for me. When i clicks on MORE button of UIActivityViewController,  Status bar change it's colour from black to white. Same result getting for Navigation bar.